# GridCoverage2DReader not reading 16 bit grayscale?

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I have a geotiff that has 16-bit gray scale pixels and GridCoverage2DReader instance only returns the nodata value. Yet both QGIS and uDig show the image and I see WGS 84 and EPSG:4326 for the geotiff properties.

I am using geoserver 2.8.2 with the DDS/Bil extension and Java 1.8.x.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I already have debug enabled for logging and did not see any exceptions thrown but did not look for debug logging for the reader. I will look again for relevant logging. I am trying to find the implementation class for the reader since I suspect what I mentioned is probably just an interface. Right now all I know is the reader is coming from a resource pool. I think I did notice one of the classes would let me get to read parameters for the reader. I will get that info and see if it makes sense. I suspect that the reader was setup by GeoServer and not the bil plugin since it has the store info and layer info for the GeoTIFF file.

I am a newbie to GeoServer but not to java.

Comment: can you turn up logging and add the relevant section from the log file